# How to play hangman?

Tags: c#

I need to create a hangman game.The problem is I'm struggling to keep the guesses there and eliminate the * characters which represent the letters not yet selected.

There is a listbox containing the entire alphabet to choose from on the form design and a label which represents the word that is being guessed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string line;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lsbLetters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myString = "bash";
            int d, counter;

            char y, letter;
            letter = Convert.ToChar(lsbLetters.SelectedItem.ToString());

            for (counter = 1; counter < myString.Length; counter++)
            {
                line = "";

                for (d = 0; d < myString.Length; d++)
                {
                    y = myString[d];

                    if (letter == myString[d])
                    {
                        line += myString[d];
                        for (int j = 1; j <= myString.Length - d; j++)
                        {
                            line += "* ";
                        }
                        lblWord.Text = line;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need the the letter to be replaced if correctly guessed, through the listbox and the others to remain * characters until they are selected, for example if a and h was selected for the current word bash.

```
*a*h

| a |
| b | 
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f | 
| g |
....
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Personally, I always did my own homework, that way I learned.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
private void lsbLetters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myString = "bash";
    char letter = Convert.ToChar(lsbLetters.SelectedItem.ToString());
    line = "";

    for (int counter = 0; counter < myString.Length; counter++)
    {
        if (letter == myString[counter])
            line += letter;
        else
            line += lblWord.Text[counter];
    }

    lblWord.Text = line;
}
```